# Turned off a server and on restart got a mount error

Tags: server, cifs

Please could somone assist?

We have an error on a server restart when moving the server to a new rack.

End of boot sequence is:

```
* Starting configure network device
* Starting Mount Network filesystems
* Stopping Mount Network filesystems
[ 56.172113] CIFS WFS: Error connecting to socket. Aborting operation
[ 56.172196] CIFS WFS: cifs_mount failed w/return code = -113
Unable to find suitable address
mountall: mount /var/linuxbackup [764] terminated with status 2
```

There was an old portable network external HDD, but that was not on at the time as I recall.

Thank you in advance

Nick

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using /var/linuxbackup then you should remove the line from /etc/fstab where the system is trying to mount that device. The entry would have the form: `//url2storage /var/linuxbackup cifs ...` You could boot into single user mode, fix /etc/fstab, then finish startup, and you should successfully complete the boot process.

Comment: Have you made any progress?